# getting file in path SPM swift

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have a package in SPM and I am dealing with file system. The problem I am facing now is my test case fails when I try getting the file like json file. here is my code and my test case.

Mt test

```
func testBundle() -> Bundle? {
        return Bundle(for: LandingPageSerializationTests.self)
    }
    
    func parseLandingPage(fromFile filename: String?) -> LandingPage? {
        let path = testBundle()?.path(forResource: filename, ofType: nil, inDirectory: kConfigFileFolder)
        XCTAssertNotNil(path)
        
        let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as Data?
        XCTAssertNotNil(data)
        
        var asDict: [String: Any]? = nil
        do {
            if let data = data {
                asDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]
            }
        } catch {
        }
        XCTAssertNotNil(asDict)
        
        return LandingPageSerialization.landingPage(fromJson: asDict)
    }
```

My Package.swift

```
let package = Package(
    name: "XXXX",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v11)],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "XXXX",
            targets: ["XXXX"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "XXXX",
            dependencies: [
            ],
            resources: [
                .process("Resources"),
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "XXXXTests",
            dependencies: ["XXXX"],
            resources: [
                .process("Resources"),
            ]
        ),

    ]
)
```

I do not know why I keep getting nil for the path despite specific name mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
resources: [
    .process("Resources"),
]
```

would be right if this was a file called Resources. If Resources is a folder, you want `.copy`, not `.process`.

Also, I don't believe you can fetch a resource from the package's test target bundle in the way you're trying to do. You need to fetch it from the package's main target bundle, which you can do by saying `Bundle.module`.

Here's a demo. This is the organization of my package:

[image]

This is my package declaration:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "XXXXX",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "XXXXX",
            targets: ["XXXXX"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "XXXXX",
            dependencies: [],
            resources: [.copy("Resources")]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "XXXXXTests",
            dependencies: ["XXXXX"]),
    ]
)
```

And this is a test method that works:

```
func testExample() throws {
    let b = Bundle.module
    let url = b.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "json", subdirectory: "Resources")
    let urlreal = try XCTUnwrap(url)
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: urlreal)
    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    let resultreal = try XCTUnwrap(result as? [String:Any]) // dictionary
    XCTAssertEqual(resultreal["name"] as? String ?? "", "Matt")
}
```

Comment: But what happens when I put them in a resource folder? or a folder Called Config

Comment: getting the path also still returns nil. `b.path(forResource: filename, ofType: nil, inDirectory: "Config")` and my Package `.process("Config/120.png")`

Comment: Revised my answer to match your original conditions more precisely.

Comment: Hi @matt I would appreciate if you could help contribute here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67907955/modifying-file-in-path-spm

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution after lookin inside the package build folder. If you dont want to ship the Mocks with your app you should configure the package like this:

1.- First put your mocks in a folder within the Tests target folder structure

[image]

2.- Then you must tell the package to copy the directory in the Test target
[image]

3.- Clean and Build your package otherwise it wont copy the newly added folder

4.- Add this Helper to your tests:

```
public enum JSONHelper {
    public static func loadJSON<Element: Decodable>(
        withFile fileName: String,
        inBundleWithName bundle: String,
        subdirectory: String) -> Element? {
        let bundle = Bundle.currentModule(name: bundle)
        var jsonData: Element?

        if let url = bundle.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json", subdirectory: subdirectory) {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                jsonData = try decoder.decode(Element.self, from: data)
                return jsonData
            } catch {
                debugPrint(error)
            }
        } else {
            debugPrint("Could not find the json file: \(fileName) in bundle: \(bundle)")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

4.5 - Add this extension:

```
public extension Foundation.Bundle {
    static func currentModule(name: String) -> Bundle {
        var thisModuleName = name + "_" + name
        var url = Bundle.main.bundleURL

        for bundle in Bundle.allBundles where bundle.bundlePath.hasSuffix(".xctest") {
            url = bundle.bundleURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
            thisModuleName = thisModuleName.appending("Tests")
        }

        url = url.appendingPathComponent("\(thisModuleName).bundle")

        guard let bundle = Bundle(url: url) else {
            fatalError("Foundation.Bundle.module could not load resource bundle: \(url.path)")
        }

        return bundle
    }
}
```

5.- After this you may load your mock file like this:

```
let response: LoginResponseModel = JSONHelper.loadJSON(withFile: "loginSuccess", inBundleWithName: "Login", subdirectory: "JSON")!
```